# ER Model recursive relationship with partial participation

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I was wondering if you can have a recursive relationship that's 1:N and has partial participation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're asking if it's possible to model trees? Yes, it is, via a binary relationship with the same domain for both its roles.

[image: Parent-Child ER diagram]

Partial participation is straightforward as long as the entity relation is defined independently of the relationship relation, allowing entities to be recorded without requiring them to be related.

In your physical model, you may need some additional technique, like a closure table, to make recursive queries easier/more efficient.